# Your IP is blacklisted - Directadmin

Tags: linux

While logging in to the directadmin control panel, it says that my IP is black listed.

"Your IP is blacklisted"

I already checked in CSF but my IP is not black listed.

Is this any error related to RBL or so? Any advice?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

That means that you had many login failures to the directadmin control panel.

To remove yourself from the blacklist, edit

> /usr/local/directadmin/data/admin/ip_blacklist

and remove your IP from the list.

For whitelisting the ip, add it to the file:

> /usr/local/directadmin/data/admin/ip_whitelist